# Unable to connect to Airflow server running on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, airflow, aws-security-group

I am trying to set up an Apache Airflow server on ec2. I managed to get it running and verify status by hitting `/health` endpoint using curl on `http://localhost:8989`. Airflow listens on port 8989 here.

The next I want is to be able to connect to the admin dashboard/UI using the browser on EC2's public IP. So I added the inbound rule in the AWS security group ec2 instance belongs to.
[image: inbound rule details]

While connecting to Airflow, I am getting the following error

```
Failed to connect to ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 8989: Operation timed out
```

Not sure what else I need to do to reach server running on ec2.

Comment: "I managed to get it running and verify status" - I assume you mean that it's running successfully on your local machine. How are you deploying it to EC2?

Comment: @jscott I meant deploy and verify on ec2. To run on ec2, I installed airflow using `pip3 install`. Then I set `AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN` and `AIRFLOW_HOME` env variables and finally run airflow webserver & schedular `airflow webserver -p 8989 &`
`airflow scheduler &`

Comment: OK. So no problems with SSH/port 22, just port 8989? Are there any network ACLs in place on the VPC subnet? Any other security groups applied to the instance? Another possibility is iptables/other firewall running on the instance, what AMI did you use?

Comment: Added rule to the subnet that allows traffic to and from 8989. Then opened port 8989 in the Ubuntu firewall and it worked :-). Amazing pointers @jscott.. happy for the outcome!

Comment: Glad that worked! I posted an answer, would appreciate it if you'd accept/vote for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can SSH to an EC2 instance, you've added a security group rule for ingress on another port, but can't reach the instance on that port, here are some other things to check:

- **Firewall running on the instance.** Amazon Linux and recent official
  Ubuntu AMIs shouldn't have iptables or some other firewall running on
  them by default, but if you're using another AMI or someone else has
  configured the EC2 instance, it's possible to have iptables/ufw or
  some other firewall running. Check processes on your instance to make
  sure you don't have a firewall.
- **[Network ACL on the VPC subnet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html).** The default ACL will permit
  traffic on all ports. It's possible that the default has been changed
  to allow traffic only on selected ports.
- **Multiple security groups assigned to the EC2 instance.** It's possible
  to assign more than one security group to the instance. Check to make
  sure you don't have a rule in some other security group that's
  blocking the port.